# OS X Host - VirtualBox 5.0 running Ubuntu 14.04.02 video/audio playback is too fast

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, audio, video

I am running a VirtualBox 5.0 on my OS X host machine with Ubuntu 14.04.02 as the guest.

The problem is, the video/audio is playing back too fast when watching Youtube videos or any kind of video/audio playback in general.

I've uninstalled VirtualBox 4.3.8 VBoxGuestAdditions and installed the version for 5.0.

And this solution I tried, but doesn't work:

http://mattmoore.org/posts/too-fast-audio-video-playback-in-linux

Anyone have any ideas on how to address this?

Comment: Also having this problem now. Did you solve it?

Comment: I just reinstalled the everything from scratch on the newer VB version.